# Handle multiple request in retrofit using executor

Tags: android, retrofit, executorservice, intentservice

I want to send multiple requests in queue in retrofit.

Solution: we can do this by using Intent service.

But i want to know how can i achieve this using executor.

**Edit**:

I am trying like,

```
return new RestAdapter.Builder() .setEndpoint(API_URL).setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
.setClient(new OkClient(new OkHttpClient()))
.setConverter(new GsonConverter(mGson)) .setExecutors(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4),null)
.build().create(ApiRequestInterface.class);
```

and then I am making 4 webservice call.

```
@GET("/user") void getInfo(@Header(KEY_AUTH)String apiToken,Callback<user> callback);
```

with different API urls. but the reponse I am not getting in sequence.